# get list of al users on farm level on SharePoint 2010 application

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, powershell-script

I am trying run below script on SP 2010 environment for getting list users on farm level. But i am getting error. Can someone please correct me.

Powershell script

---

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

## Output Report File

$currentLocation = (Get-Location).Path
$outputReport = $currentLocation + "\" + "SharePointUsers.csv"

## Write CSV File Header

## Array to hold user data

$UserDataCollection = @()

## Get All Web Applications and iterate through

$WebAppsColl = Get-SPWebApplication

foreach($WebApp in $WebAppsColl)
{
    Write-host "Scanning Web Application:"$WebApp.Name
    #Get All site collections and iterate through
    $SitesColl = $WebApp.Sites
    
    foreach ($Site in $SitesColl) 
    {
        Write-host "Scanning Site Collection:"$Site.URL
        
 
            foreach ($web in $WebsColl) 
            {
                Write-host "Scanning Web:"$Web.URL
                #Get All Users of the Web
                $UsersColl = $web.AllUsers  #get all users programmatically 
                    #list all users 
                    foreach ($user in $UsersColl) 
                    {
                           if($User.IsDomainGroup -eq $false) 
                            {
                                $UserData = New-Object PSObject
               
                                $UserData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "UserLogin" -value $user.UserLogin.ToString()
                                $UserData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "DisplayName" -value $user.displayName.ToString()
                                $UserData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "E-mailID" -value $user.Email.ToString()
 
                                $UserDataCollection += $UserData
                            }
                    }
            $Web.dispose()
            }
         $site.dispose()
        }
    }    
    #Remove duplicates
    $UserDataCollection = $UserDataCollection | sort-object -Property  {$_.UserLogin } -Unique
 
    #Remove duplicates and export all users to excel
    $UserDataCollection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $OutputReport -NoTypeInformation
          
    Write-host "Total Number of Unique Users found:"$UserDataCollection.Length

### Error i am get as below:

Sort-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Propert
 '.
At C:\Users\sp_farm\Farmlevelusers.ps1:57 char:71
+     $UserDataCollection = $UserDataCollection | sort-object -Property  <<<<
{$_.UserLogin } -Unique
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Sort-Object], ParameterBin
   dingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.SortObjectCommand

Export-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LiteralP
th'.
At C:\Users\sp_farm\Farmlevelusers.ps1:60 char:50
+     $UserDataCollection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath <<<<  $OutputReport -NoTyp
Information
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBind
   ingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.ExportCsvCommand

Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The script you provide doesn’t seem to be a complete version. 
The error message indicates the parameters and the cmdlets are not matching.

Here’s another sample script to get all users on farm level for your reference.

[Get All Users In A SharePoint 2010/13/16 Farm Using PowerShell Script.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-all-users-in-a-sharepoint-20101316-farm-using-powershell-script)